# Which books feature Fitz Farseer?

Tags: realm-of-the-elderlings, robin-hobb

I have just been reading *The Fools Assassin* and I was wondering if the character Fitz Farseer is involved in the plots of any of the other books Robin Hobb has written.

**Has she written any other books with this character?**

Comment: The three books Assassin's Apprentice, Royal Assassin and Assassin's Quest all have Fitz Farseer as the main character.

Comment: @Bellerophon - That sounds like an answer to me

Comment: The wiki has a list of appearances; http://robinhobbelderlings.wikia.com/wiki/FitzChivalry_Farseer. I've no idea if its accurate though

Comment: @Valorum I was just checking that he didn't feature in any others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you started reading "Realm of Elderlings" from "The Fools Assassin" then you started it almost from the end.

Fitz is first introduced in the "Farseer Trilogy" ("Assassin's Apprentice", "Royal Assassin" and "Assassin's Quest"), that describe his youth on the Farseer court, his training as an assassin and his first attempts to master Wit and Skill. The main story of the trilogy revolves around court intrigue and the war with Red Ship Riders.

Fitz returns fifteen years later in the "Tawny Man" trilogy - "Fool's Errand", "Golden Fool" and "Fool's Fate" (there is also a "Liveship trilogy" that happens between "Farseer" and "Tawny Man", but it takes action in different kingdom, Fitz is not there in person but his "alive" figure is carved on a liveship). Plot is focused on persecuted Wit users and attempt to restore the Six Duches to the former glory.

After this we have again series that picks picks up the resolution of "Tawny Man" and "Liveship trilogy" called "The Rain Wild Chronicles" - Fitz is not present here.

And in the final trilogy is the one that you just finished - "The Fitz and the Fool" ("Fool's Assassin", "Fool's Quest" and upcoming "Assassin's Fate").

In all books where Fitz is present, he is the main character and the narrator of the story, except the last trilogy where some chapters are told from the perspective of another character.

Answer (score 3):

Fitz Farseer is the main character in three books (the Farseer trilogy) which document his arrival at the Royal Court and his life there. These are Assassin's Apprentice, Royal Assassin and Assassin's Quest. He is also a character in the  Fitz and the Fool's trilogy (Fool's Assasin, Fool's Quest and Assasin's Fate). As well as featuring in the Tawny Man trilogy (Fool's Errand, the Golden Fool, and Fools Fate).

Comment: And his likeness is carved into the Liveship Trader's trilogy, and probably all the derivatives thereof...

Comment: He is always main character of those books - he is the first person narrator (except the "Fitz an Fool" trilogy  when some chapters are narrated by Bee)